# Making groups inside array and connecting to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

For example with the word 'stack' ->

The Main array:

**MainArray** = Array ( [0] => g [1] => g [**2**] => s [**3**] => t [**4**] => a [**5**] => c [**6**] => k [7] => d [8] => v [9])

The Array which holds the Position (key) of the word inside the other array

**PositionArray** = Array ( [0] => **2** [1] => **3** [2] => **4** [3] => **5** [4] => **6** )

I want to group the position array values inside the main arrays keys. Myself I tought about the following:

```
echo $MainArray[PositionArray[0]];
echo $MainArray[PositionArray[1]];
echo $MainArray[PositionArray[2]];
echo $MainArray[PositionArray[3]];
echo $MainArray[PositionArray[4]];
```

But then still I did not make a group or something inside the other array, I only output the word 'stack' using the MainArray.

I want this group because later on I will put My array in a tabel for example:

g - g - s 
t - a - c 
k - d - v

Then with Jquery I want that when I hover any letter of stack ( so the s, t, a, c or k) I want it to change the font color of the whole word stack. So for example if I hover 't' the word stack gets a differtent font color, and when I click it I want it to stay like that.

I tried long acomplimishing this but I have yet to suceed so that is why I seek help here.

Comment: you want to send array as json  using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Then use array to build table in javascript

Answer (score 1):

As [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) said, you've got to encode your arrays with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), then you put them into your variables

```
    var MainArray = {"0":"q","1":"s","2":"t","3":"a", "4":"c", "5":"k"};

    var PositionArray ={"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4","4":"5"};

    var Main = $.map(MainArray, function(el) { return el; })
    var Positions = $.map(PositionArray, function(el) { return parseInt(el); })

    var attr = "";
    for(var i=0; i<Main.length;i++){    
      if(Positions.indexOf(i) != -1){
        attr="letter";
        console.log(i);
      }else{
        attr="";
      }
      $('div').append('<span class="'+attr+'">'+MainArray[i]+'</span>')
    }
    $('.letter').on('mouseover', function() {
      $('.letter').css('color', 'red');
    }).on('mouseout', function(){
        $('.letter').css('color', 'black');
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

I hope that helped you out.

Comment: I did not get it to work yet but I can at least go ahead and try new things and such, thanks :).

Comment: at least you understand the logique?

Comment: I am trying to understand what is going on but I'm not that familiar with Jquery so I need some time :P

Comment: You got it? Or should I provide you with explanations?